# self join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, nested, hierarchy

| emp_id | emp | level | manager_id | manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | sam | 1 | 100 | sam |
| 200 | jack | 2 | 100 | sam |
| 300 | jill | 2 | 100 | sam |
| 400 | claire | 3 | 200 | jack |
| 500 | reed | 3 | 300 | jill |
| 600 | derrick | 4 | 400 | claire |
| 700 | bill | 4 | 500 | reed |

I have a table with employees and their respective managers in column 'emp' and 'manager' respectively. The numbers in the 'level' column represent different levels within an organisation for the employees in column 'emp'.

How do i write a query to get the manager name from the previous level as an entry in step and so forth.

| emp_id | emp | level | manager_id | manager | l1 | l2 | l3 | l4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | sam | 1 | 100 | sam | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 200 | jack | 2 | 100 | sam | sam | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 300 | jill | 2 | 100 | sam | sam | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 400 | claire | 3 | 200 | jack | sam | jack | NULL | NULL |
| 500 | reed | 3 | 300 | jill | sam | jill | NULL | NULL |
| 600 | derrick | 4 | 400 | claire | sam | jack | claire | NULL |
| 700 | bill | 4 | 500 | reed | sam | jill | reed | NULL |

Comment: There's something that may be flawed in your input data. There could be many middle managers at say, level 4 or 7, but I see only one person at each level. Is this true? If not, how would you identify who's the manager of Claire or Paul? There's no clear indication how to correcly *link* people in the data.

Comment: Manager of Claire is Paul as indicated in row 3. Paul's manager data is not represented here. in the real data, there are many managers at the same level and many levels between 4 and 7 i.e., 5, 6, i have not indicated that in the example above.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you use meaningful column names, instead of A,B,C?

Comment: I have updated the column names.

Comment: From the sample data it looks like there might be a table structure issue. Can you split the managers into a new table? It looks like `sam` is always the step 1 manager, `bill` is always step 2 and so on.

Comment: Please also update the description accordingly `column B`, `column D`

Comment: Your question is not clear. Looking from the sample data and required result, `step 1` to `step 9` is fixed and you don't need recursive query at all. Please review and edit your question with better sample data and required result

Comment: i have updated the column names and better explained the sample data, hope this helps. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a recursive query.  One that keeps joining on the next level until there are no more levels to join to.

That can be used to get all of an employees managers, each manager as a new row.

You then want to pivot those rows in to columns.  Note, however, that SQL is statically and strongly typed, which means that if you want a pivoted view, you have to choose in advance how many columns you're going to have.

For example...

```
WITH
  recurse_upwards AS
(
  SELECT
    emp.emp_id,
    emp.emp          AS emp_name,
    0                AS level,
    mgr.emp_id       AS manager_id,
    mgr.emp          AS manager_name,
    mgr.manager_id   AS next_manager_id
  FROM
    example   AS emp
  LEFT JOIN
    example   AS mgr
      ON mgr.emp_id = emp.manager_id

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    emp.emp_id,
    emp.emp_name,
    emp.level + 1,
    mgr.emp_id,
    mgr.emp,
    mgr.manager_id
  FROM
    recurse_upwards   AS emp
  INNER JOIN
    example           AS mgr
      ON mgr.emp_id = emp.next_manager_id
)
SELECT
  emp_id,
  emp_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN level = 0 THEN manager_id   END)  AS manager_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN level = 0 THEN manager_name END)  AS manager_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN level = 1 THEN manager_name END)  AS manager_1_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN level = 2 THEN manager_name END)  AS manager_2_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN level = 3 THEN manager_name END)  AS manager_3_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN level = 4 THEN manager_name END)  AS manager_4_name
FROM
  recurse_upwards
GROUP BY
  emp_id,
  emp_name
ORDER BY
  emp_id
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/Tj7rZ5bT

Comment: When i run the above query, the recursion goes into infinite loop

Comment: @user2715877 Not with the sample data you gave. See the demo I linked. If you get an infinite loop, then you have a problem with your data. If you're unable to find that circular reference yourself, raise another question about using sql to find circular references in adjacency lists. I'll be happy to have a look.

Comment: I identified the circular reference. With the above code, it takes the last row in the table and repeats that entry infinite times. With the way my data is structured, running the above code would run the first 6 rows and repeat the last row (i.e., Bill) infinite times.  Also, in the first row manager_id and manager is not NULL for level 1 employee, i have updated the table to reflect that.

Comment: @user2715877 If that's the only circular reference, then just add `AND mgr.emp_id <> emp.manager_id` to the recursive party of the query. https://dbfiddle.uk/Fq6rjM2M

Comment: This condition AND mgr.emp_id <> emp.manager_id breaks the infinite recursive loop!!

Comment: However after you pivot the results, level 2 employess (i.e., jack and jill should have 'sam' as manager_1_name, it should not be NULL and level 3 employees (i.e., claire and reed should have 'sam' as manager_1_name and jack and jill as manager_2_name respectively.

Comment: so what's the happening with the result is;                                                                     For a level 4 employee, let's take derrick for example : expected result should be manager_1_name : sam, manager_2_name: jack, manager_3_name: claire.               but the result i am getting is manager_1_name : jack, manager_2_name: sam and it is adding them as separate rows instead of appending those values in the same row and it is retaining it's immediate manager as an additional row. So for 'derrick' i end up with 3 rows and the manager_1 and maanger_2 order is swapped.

Comment: This answer shows that Bill's managers are Reed then Jill then Sam, that Derrick's managers are Claire then Jack then Sam, and so on. Manager0 is an employee's immediate manager, Manager1, is that manager's manager, and so on. If you want a different output, just adapt that pivot, SO isn't a place for moving goalposts and long conversations.

Comment: For example: https://dbfiddle.uk/Rs1A2a7x